# Unable to get scaffold-dbcontext to run using connection string name

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a database context that I am trying to update using DB scaffolding.
The command I am using in package manager console is:

```
Scaffold-DbContext Name="pwa_db" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data -Force
```

My appsettings.json looks like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "pwa_db": "Server=[My Server];Database=[My DB];Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

yet when I run the command I get this error:

```
"A named connection string was used, but the name 'pwa_db' was not found in the application's configuration. Note that named connection strings are only supported when using 'IConfiguration' and a service provider, such as in a typical ASP.NET Core application. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=850912 for more information."
```

The strange thing is that this context was generated using this command so I'm not sure why it would stop working now.
I could easily get around this by just using the full connection string in the command instead of a named connection but then the DB context is generated with the connection string inside which I would prefer to avoid because you always get a warning like this:

```
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. You can avoid scaffolding the connection string by using the Name= syntax to read it from configuration - see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2131148. For more guidance on storing connection strings, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263.
```

The warning itself I'm not so concerned about because I'm using a trusted connection, so no credentials are being stored and I'm not expecting the source to ever leave our office.

Can anyone tell me what other configuration bits I might need to look at or what other issues may be at play? Because I can't see what is going wrong from the docs linked in any of the messages.

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the connection string to the appsettings.development.json file too?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still does not work after copying it there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but maybe this can help someone else.

It works for me and I followed what you did in the scaffolding command and the json "ConnectionStrings".  The error mentions IConfiguration.  You are probably missing the connection set up in the Startup class.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
          ...
        services.AddDbContext<DTCCDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("pwa_db")));
          ...
    }...
```